# Need a solution to this problem of Document Library privacy in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am the Site collection administrator for our intranet sharepoint site along with an other person. We have a requirement where in we need to put Sales Documents on our sharepoint site which is not to be seen by anyone else including the site collection/site administrators other than the Sales department. Is there any way this can be done? One idea I had was to create a password protected document library. Can we do that in SharePoint 2013? Please give me a solution to this

Comment: Keep in mind that the SharePoint admins, and possibly the system and SQL Server admins will all be able to access the documents and other content regardless of how you configure the security on any securable container (site collection, site, document library, etc.) in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate site collection fro the Sales department and remove yourselves as the site collection administrators once the site is configured.

Basically, if you are a site collection admin, you have access to everything in the site collection.

Comment: That was a solution I was thinking. I just wanted to know if there is any other way to do implement it.